# How to bake Mantaflow simulation in version 2.83

Tags: fluid-simulation

I tried development versions before, and there I could use Object > Quick Effects > Quick Liquid and there'd be bake data / bake mesh buttons in the Physics Properties.

Now, it seems like the bake happens in the background, and I don't know how to re-bake the simulation after adding e.g. an effector.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to Settings > Cache > Type > Modular:

[image]